# Runtime NavMesh Builder source mesh combined mesh is skipped because it does not allow read access

Tags: unity, ai, mesh, navmesh

I'm getting this error:

> Runtime NavMesh Builder source mesh combined mesh is skipped because
>   it does not allow read access

I checked all the models and it has the read permission. I also noticed, that in some cases unchecking the static checkbox helps and I'm getting a smaller amount of these errors.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by setting every object in my scene to non-static. The problem was, that the NavMesh Builder was trying to combine static and non-static meshes.

Comment: If this solved your issue, could you mark your answer as correct? This would prevent it from being bumped to the homepage for new users to answer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to fix this is to change in NavMeshSurface/Use Geometry from Render Meshes to Physics Colliders.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).